# xargs does not end after reaching EOF

Tags: bash, xargs

I use this bash command:

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -d $"\n" -n 1 -P 250 php script.php $1
```

When it reaches the end of file for `urls.txt` it does nothing.
My script if it's matter does connect to websites and is looking for `<a href>`, however if I run the script manually `php script.php http://url` is working fine, even with a couple hundred of websites in the `urls.txt` while running xargs command, but if the file is large enough(a couple of MBs) it does nothing when reaches **EOF**.

My guess is there is no problem with the script, somehow xargs can't detect the end of file and it keeps waiting for inputs. Any solution?

**EDIT:** I also tried to `tail -n1 urls.txt` to check if there is any null data to EOF and everything is ok.

Comment: $"\n" should be $'\n' is the first thing I noticed. Although xargs parses C escape sequences in -d, so shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I tried same result. It does get blocked.

Comment: xargs has `-a` option, use this instead of `cat`. What is `$1` ??

Comment: $1 is the target while reading the file. (-n 1 for each line), (-P 250, multi tread, 250 times).

Comment: No `-n1` let `xargs` add 1 argument per run, but you won't specify that using `$1`. Maybe try `xargs -a urls.txt -I{} -P250 php script.php {}` << Does this work?

Comment: So `ps | grep php` confirms that the php scripts have all finished running? But the `xargs` command still does not finish?

Comment: Might be a dos line endings issue ?!

Comment: @sourcejedi yes, exactly.

Comment: @pLumo no, the urls.txt file is created on my linux machine and then used with script.php

Comment: okay, did you try my suggested xargs command?

Comment: What does `script.php` do when it is run without an argument? Maybe there is an extra empty line in the input file?

Comment: @pLumo your solution work, please anwer it below so I can vote it. Thank you.

Comment: @pLumo, I think using cat in conjunction with xargs + large files cause the trouble. I'm not an expert in bash or php but this is my guess.

Comment: I don't think... used pipe from `cat` for way larger files ..

Comment: the `xargs` source code is a bit opaque to me. if you think there's a bug in xargs, you might try installing its debug symbols (there should be instructions for this specific to your Linux distribution), then `gdb xargs`, `run -a urls.txt -d "\n" -n 1 -P 250 php script.php`, wait for your php scripts to finish, then Ctrl+Z followed by `backtrace`.  That would show *where* it is waiting. If you can read C you could then start trying to work out *why* :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your `xargs`-script is not working, maybe there is no newline at the end or some other issue with `-d` option. As a smaller list is working, maybe some line has problematic characters.

So, instead of using `-d $'\n'`, I prefer using `-I{}` to avoid problems and to gain more control. For the command, use `{}`, which is replaced by each line.

Also, you have a [UUOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), `xargs` provides `-a` or `--arg-file` option:

> **-a file, --arg-file=file** Read items from file instead of standard input.  If you use this option, stdin remains unchanged when commands are run.  Otherwise, stdin is redirected from /dev/null.

Try:

```
xargs -a urls.txt -I{} -P 250 php script.php {}
```

Comment: `-d` and `-I` are orthogonal. If OP's input has whitespace or quotes in it they'll need `-d`.